# Adding "link" action to a submit button

Tags: javascript

So, I have this type="submit" button for a profile picture to be uploaded and saved.

For a specific page, I want this button to have extra function so that when an user clicks this 'submit' button, then the user goes to a different page (of course, the photo is successfully saved).

I am thinking of javascript for this.

For example, here is the steps that I want:

1. An user uploads a profile picture (using a different button)
2. The user clicks "Save changes" (type='submit' button)
3. Once the save is confirmed, then the user is redirect to a different page.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks.

EDIT: (Note that it is wordpress) This is the code that I have so far (simplified version)

```
    <div class="submit_it">

        <?php if (isset($args["{$template}_button_primary"]) ) { ?>
            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $args["{$template}_button_primary"]; ?>" class="my_button" />
        <?php } ?>          

    </div>
```

So what it does is that, the button saves the changes (such as profile picture).

Now, I am thinking instead of using javascript, I will simply add `if` statement
that the user will be redirected to a different page (for example, demo.com/another_page) only on a specific page (for example, post_id=1222)

What do you guys think?

Comment: Is the Save button making changes server side or just redirecting them?

Comment: Please provide some sample code to demonstrate what you've done so far and what you're having problems with.

Comment: Contrary to the common misconception, there is no "best" way to do something this broad. The "best" way would be to start implementing the logic you've already designed. If you run into a specific problem feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: (That said, what you've described sounds a lot like the default functionality of HTML forms so I don't see why you would use JavaScript for something like this.)

Comment: Tags will be automatically added to the title and shown with the question, no need to manually add them. :)

Comment: Look up "POST-redirect-GET".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('form').submit(function(){
    $.post('http://example.com/upload', function() {
      window.location = 'http://google.com';
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

I think this is what you are looking for. If you are willing to use jquery.

Comment: Unless jQuery is specifically asked for or tagged, please assume OP wants to use native JS.

Comment: Just trying to help people and I get downvoted like crazy. My answer does what he needs, and using javascript with a library. Whats so wrong about it. If I could comment a post, I could ask the OP about JQuery, but I can't the question was so open that you could easily think about that.

Comment: You are right. I was not clear enough. I decided not to use either javascript nor jquery. But I do appreciate your help alot. I marked your solution as accepted as I could use this next time. Thanks Veslor! =)